# Publishing and linking files within a gh-pages branch in github

Tags: github, github-pages

[Background: I don't have more than passing familiarity with html or other programming languages (except for the statistical package [R]), but in trying to follow a Coursera course I'm facing the challenge of presenting an assignment in gh-pages.]

I have a `gh-pages` branch [here](https://github.com/RInterested/Stuff), which I labeled it `Stuff`, and contains an `index.html` file, accessible through this address http://rinterested.github.io/Stuff/ online. This is the Home or "anchor" page of the website, but I want to create other pages within http://rinterested.github.io/Stuff/. To this effect, I have been unsuccessfully playing with a toy document that at this point is within the same `gh-pages` folder and labeled `Plotting-With-R.md`. Why `.md`? Because after much searching online it got a lead indicating that this would turn the page into html... Don't ask.

Well, it's not working. Although the `index.html` is clearly accessible online the `Plotting-With-R.md` doesn't seem to be. So can you please help me with whatever I am doing wrong (preferably working directly with Github (not git)) to get this extra page published online, and linked to `index.html`?

Comment: shouldn't your `href` use the filename `Plotting_With_R.md` not `Plotting_With_R/`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, please?

Comment: line 44 of your index.html points to `Plotting_With_R/` not to the file itself.

Comment: I just changed, but it still doesn't work... Any thoughts?

Comment: sorry man, i'm still trying to figure out gh-pages too

Comment: Change your href on line 44 to this `http://rinterested.github.io/Stuff/Plotting-with-R.html`. Plus, this website helped me understand a few things: http://learn.andrewmunsell.com/learn/jekyll-by-example/tutorial

Comment: Yes!!!!!! THANK YOU. Can you please consider writing it as an answer so I can up vote it and accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to access your `Plotting-with-R.md` file, you need to link to the html version since Jekyll converts it from `.md` to `.html`.

Comment: Hi there. Your link is dead, and the answer rather relies upon it. Would you remove the link and summarise what it said, in the answer?

Comment: I removed the link since the actual contents of the webpage was irrelevant. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I notice the link remains there, despite not being of use to any readers. Would you flesh out what was there, or some other useful information, to take its place? What should an `href` on line 44 be changed to? (You could just delete the last sentence entirely, but I am not sure it would be as useful as an upvoted/accepted answer ought to be).

Comment: You say "...link remains...not being of use to any readers...flesh out what was there". I don't know how to explain this but it does *not* matter what was there. What was important was that the OP change his hyperlink to the html version of his markdown file not to the markdown file directly since Jekyll converts MD files to HTML files. I am leaving my post as it is since it helped the OP and was the answer he was looking for. If you are an editor, and feel a strong desire to change it, feel free to make it say what you want.

Comment: OK. In future, if a link is no longer accessible, please remove it entirely - once one person discovers it 404s, we might as well save that inconvenience for everyone else!

Answer (score 1):

Well, as github pages is proceed by [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), you have to follow some rules :

- all [static pages](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/) will simply be copied `toto.md` will become `toto.md`, or `titi.css` will become `titi.css` in the generated site without any processing : *copied as is*.
- any page with a [front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) will be processed toto.md will become toto.html.

So, your `Plotting-With-R.md` page must start with

```
---
---
<!doctype html>
...
```

to be rendered as `Plotting-With-R.html`.

Note: you can remove useless code before the doctype

```
Color coded factors:
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/....
```

Take some times to read [Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/) it worth the price.

Comment: I just posted the screen capture of the changes that I made to the `.md` document following your prompt in your post. Is that what you meant? (the horizontal lines don't need to be included, right?).

Comment: ... I see... the dash dash dash is not dot dot dot... I'm going through the hyperlinks.  Two rows of ---'s?